# ISessionFactoryKeyProvider missing from CommonServiceLocator when upgrading NHibernate from 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller, spring.net, sharp-architecture

I have a ASP.NET MVC application that uses Spring.NET 1.2 for dependecy injection and NHibernate 2.1 for ORM. It has been running on MVC 3, using S#arp Architecture in a slightly modified version which we have been compiling ourselves, something I am now striving to get rid of. (I.e. I am going to start using referenced SharpArch .dlls instead of pure source code.)

The initialization of Spring is done using tips taken from [here](http://blog.alexkyprianou.com/2011/03/07/using-spring-net-with-mvc-3/), as well as using the SpringServiceLocatorAdapter found [here](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns.SpringAdapters.Tests/SpringServiceLocatorAdapter.cs?r=bf38e11934cbfb402065f3191f5f8d5147895da2). NH is initialized using SharpArch's NHibernateSession.Init, which is given our two assemblypaths. The mapping is done with HBM XML files.

The decision to move to NH 3 led to a serious case of DLL Hell, due to which I of course had to update FluentNH, NH Validator, SharpArch, Spring, and Castle Windsor binaries. To get things working a lot of manual labor was needed, changing references and doing minor code fixes. This was all expected.

Now I've got the software running well enough that Spring is initialized and the DI done correctly. But when a repository tries using it's Session object, I get the following error.

> Error creating object with name '' :
>   no services of type
>   'SharpArch.NHibernate.ISessionFactoryKeyProvider'
>   defined

I've been trying to figure out the cause of this for the best part of a day now. 
It seems to me like SpringServiceLocatorAdapter is obsolete, but I can find no information regarding that. Also, simply removing the use of it results in repositories' Sessions being null and thus NullReferenceExceptions. But as far as I know the problem could just as well be the way NH is initialized.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I'm having a hard time since I'm not the one who setup the system to begin with, and lists of breaking changes for the version upgrades are hard to find.

Thanks a lot! I will of course provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register an implmentation of ISessionFactoryKeyProvider with spring, the default implementation is DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider, in windsor, the statement would look like this:

```
        container.Register(
                Component.For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I added an object <object id="sessionFactoryKeyProvider" type="SharpArch.NHibernate.DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider" singleton="true" /> to my Spring.xml and that did the trick.